# Pandas update excel file with formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, file

I have an excel file which has multiple sheets and special formatting (colors, symbols, etc...).

In Python I know that I can read the file into a data frame, update certain columns and then write the file back but it looses all formatting and gets overwritten.

Is there a way to open the file and just ***update the values*** of certain columns, keeping other sheets untouched and formatting as is?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use openpyxl in this way for example:

```
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='mypath\myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.cell(coordinate="A1").value = 2
wb.save("mypath\myfile.xlsx")
```

Where the cell A1 has a particular format. Its format stays the same and only the value of the cell changes.

To read the value of the cell, you can use this:

```
ws.cell(row=row_number, column=column_number).value
```

To change values of a column with a for loop, this is an option:

```
new_data = ['a','b','c','d']
for index, cell in enumerate(ws['A']):
    cell.value = new_data[index]
```

Comment: Can I do this for an entire column? would it just be ws.column instead of ws.cell?

Comment: In the version of openpyxl i have i cannot check. According to the documentation https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/tutorial.html there is ws.column. But anyway you can use a for loop for it, or cell_range = ws['A1':'A10']

Comment: @MustardTiger I've added an example with a for loop to replace a column